# Role Authorization in Asp.Net Core 3 adding roles from class properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-core-3.0

I am familiar with how to use Authorize header in single & multiple authorization scenarios but given the following intended changes in the code base, I cannot figure out how to implement this with cluttering up the class code with additional properties which are multiple authorizations.

I have the following AuthorizationLevel class

```
public class AuthorizationLevel
{
    public static class Roles
    {
        public const string Admin = "Admin";
        public const string Developer = "DevOps";
        public const string OfficeManager = "OfficeManager";
        public const string Customer = "Customer";
        public const string Distributor = "Distributor";
        public const string Registered = "Basic";
    }
}
```

In the controller, if I didn't have this class I would do something like

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admins, Customers")]
```

But I prefer to have a class defining all the roles so I could do something like

```
[Authorize(Roles = AuthorizationLevel.Roles.Admin, AuthorizationLevel.Roles.Customer)]
```

The problem is that in this scenario, the parameter expected after the comma is a policy, so I tried this .

```
[Authorize(Roles = $"{AuthorizationLevel.Roles.Admin}, {AuthorizationLevel.Roles.Customer}")]
```

Which the editor did not like and should've worked because that code should be creating a comma delimited string.

How can I (or can't I) use this class in this scenario, rather than having to create additional properties in the class that combine multiple levels, i.e.

```
public const string AdminCust = "Admin, Customer";
```

Comment: You can't so having multiple variables for various combinations as consts is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implemenent a custom attribute:

```
public class RolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public RolesAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        if (roles != null)
            Roles = string.Join(",", roles);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
[Roles(AuthorizationLevel.Roles.Admin, AuthorizationLevel.Roles.Customer)]
```